# SailsJS as API and Nginx: Restrict external access

Tags: angularjs, api, nginx, sails.js, restrict

I'm running SailsJS on a digitalocean droplet (MEAN Stack with nginx). All my requests are mapped to my Angular frontend except those on **/api** which are mapped to a **proxy_pass** on **port 1337** (on which Sails runs). This procedure works fine.

Now I'd like to restrict the access to my API to only allow requests from my frontend. I already tried to **deny / allow** from within my nginx config but this blocks the the user request itself. I tried several answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585513/sails-js-0-10-x-how-to-listen-on-localhost-only) as well but they didn't work out.

What would be the recommended way to limit access to my Sails API to localhost? I'd like to run multiple apps on my droplet and use Sails as my API that should only be accessible by the apps in my droplet.

My nginx config:

```
upstream sails_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:1337;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    server_name domain.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /opt/domain/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_http_version               1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection      "";
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        client_max_body_size             500M;
    }
}
```

– Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this because angular runs in your client, so you need to get IP from all you users. You can use something simple that works with trustes proxys

`var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress`

or use some more complex and trusted like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310355)

Comment: Thank for your reply @Makah! Surprisingly I got this to work by adding the `host: '127.0.0.1'` attribute to my `local.js`sails config (I tried this before and it didn't worked out). Now nginx redirects all external requests to my frontend index and api requests of the frontend to 127.0.0.1:1337. I'll do some further testing...